# matching POST route rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I am trying to upload a photo but after I press the upload button, I get this error. I am new to rails 4 so I'm not sure what I am missing.

My logic is when I click the submit button. This will cause the `create` action to fire and create a `IncomePicture` object and store it in my database.

```
No route matches [POST] "/income_pictures/new"
```

Routes:

```
root_path                   GET      /                                   static_pages#home
income_pictures_path        GET      /income_pictures(.:format)          income_pictures#index
                            POST     /income_pictures(.:format)          income_pictures#create
new_income_picture_path     GET      /income_pictures/new(.:format)      income_pictures#new
edit_income_picture_path    GET      /income_pictures/:id/edit(.:format) income_pictures#edit
income_picture_path         GET      /income_pictures/:id(.:format)      income_pictures#show
                            PATCH    /income_pictures/:id(.:format)      income_pictures#update
                            PUT      /income_pictures/:id(.:format)      income_pictures#update
                            DELETE   /income_pictures/:id(.:format)      income_pictures#destroy
```

Controller:

```
class IncomePicturesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @income_picture = IncomePicture.new
  end

  def create
    @income_picture = IncomePicture.new(IncomePicture_params)
    if @income_picture.save
      flash[:notice] = "Income picture successfully uploaded"
      redirect_to @income_picture
    end
  end

  def show
    @income_picture = IncomePicture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @income_picture = IncomePicture.all
  end

  private
    def IncomePicture_params
      params.require(:income_picture).permit(:image, :name)
    end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for :income_picture, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You will need to lowercase your IncomPicture_params method. Ruby is case-sensitive and the rails way to write a method is lowercase. Starting with an uppercase letter indicates a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `form_for @income_picture` rather than `form_for :income_picture`.

From [the form guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form): Using a symbol creates a form to new_income_picture_path, i.e. /income_picture/new whereas using a populated instance variable creates a form to income_pictures_path, i.e. income/pictures. Both set the form's method to POST. However, there's no such route as POSTing to /income_picture/new/, which is what caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

**form_for**

To elaborate on the accepted answer, you have to remember that when calling [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), Rails does some pretty amazing things:

> 1. It takes an ActiveRecord *object* and builds a "route" out of it (from the model)
> 2. It populates the form with the ActiveRecord object's data
> 3. It allows you to retain a perceived persistent state on the form (by perpetuating the data)

The problem you have is you're passing a simple `symbol` to the form - which prevents Rails from being able to accurately access the data required to make the 3 "magic" steps above possible.

This means you'll get random errors like the one you're seeing (IE in the absence of an ActiveRecord object, Rails will just use the same URL that you have on your page - `/new`)

--

**ActiveRecord**

The way to fix the issue you have is to replace the `symbol` with an `ActiveRecord object`, which was suggested in the accepted answer.

The reason why using an `ActiveRecord object` (`@instance_variable`) works is because of `Ruby`'s core functionality -- it's a *object orientated* language. Being object orientated, it means that each time you populate an `ActiveRecord` object, you'll basically give Rails a series of *other* information, such as `model_name` etc.

This means when you pass the `@instance_variable` to the `form_for` method, Rails will be able to take the data from ActiveRecord & process it on screen for you